# Wildcard in if and elif statement

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, symbology, layouts, feature-layer

I am using Python to update layer names and symbology on a map layout. Some layer names may be different so I was attempting to use a wildcard, but am not having luck. I am not receiving an error, but nothing is changing. The layer name could be named FirePoint_1, FirePoint_2, ... etc.

```py
for lyr in mp.listLayers():

    if lyr.isFeatureLayer:
        sym = lyr.symbology
        
        if lyr.name == "FirePoint*":
                lyr.name = "Fire Origin"
                sym.renderer.symbol.applySymbolFromGallery("Fire Station")
                lyr.symbology = sym
```

Comment: Try: `if lyr.name.startswith('FirePoint'):`

Comment: Thank you kindly - that works perfectly.

Comment: Pure Python questions are better researched in [so]

Comment: Or `if 'FirePoint' in lyr.name:`

Answer (score 4):

You can use Python's [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for wildcards.

Here is how you can do it with [re.match()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match)

```
import re

for lyr in mp.listLayers():

    if lyr.isFeatureLayer:
        sym = lyr.symbology

        if re.match("FirePoint.+", lyr.name):
            lyr.name = "Fire Origin"
            sym.renderer.symbol.applySymbolFromGallery("Fire Station")
            lyr.symbology = sym
```